# I want to include another Jinja2 template in an Ansible context in Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have an Ansible playbook that sets a lot of variables. One the playbooks has this task:

```
- name: create config file 
  template:
    src: 'templates/main_config.j2'
    dest: "{{ tmp_dir }}/main_config.json"
```

The template `main_config.j2` writes strings that are defined as variables in the parent Ansible playbooks and tasks.

I want to include another Jinja2 template based on a value of an Ansible variable.

```
{% include "./templates/configurations.j2" %}, 
{% include "./templates/security.j2" %},
{% include './templates/' + {{ job }} + '_steps.j2' %}
```

`job` is a Ansible variable set in a parent playbook.

This is not working. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't need to open a Jinja2 expression (`{{ ... }}`) to refer to a variable inside a statement (`{% ... %}`). You can use the variable name directly:

```
{% include './templates/' + job + '_steps.j2' %}
```

Comment: can it be used without the `template` module?